# iPhone: How can I store a high score to disk

Tags: iphone, persistence

I have a int which is my high score:

```
NSInteger highScore;
```

I want to store it persistently to disk

Do I have to convert it to a string, then write the string to a file, then parse it back when I want to read it.  Or is there a better way to store small amounts of data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try saving the integer in [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

There is an example of someone storing an integer in there [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614468/iphone-sdk-default-nsuserdefaults).

Comment: great! I thought there would be a simple answer in the iphone sdk

Comment: @Robert: Simpler than `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:highScore forKey:@"highScore"]`? I find that unlikely.

This is what NSUserDefaults was meant for. It's a one-liner. Doesn't get any simpler.

Comment: @Dan Ray: he means that this solution (NSUserDefaults) is simpler than writing to disk by hand. As in, when he wrote the question, he "thought there would be a simpler answer in the iphone sdk" than converting to string, writing to file, then parsing string.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the NSInteger to a file withougt converting it to a string like so:

```
NSInteger foo = 134;
fwrite(&foo, sizeof(NSInteger),1, filePointer);
```

Then you can just read it back again using fread the same way.